# How do you run a main class with a Java class? And error:cannot access file

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a Java program where its class is in a different file or different class file. I have this main class and it won't access the class or file that I made. It's saying error:cannot access (name of the class) which is Employee.

```
public class EmployeeMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee e1=new Employee;
        Employee e2=new Employee;

        e1.setEmpID(1001);
        e1.setLastName("Dela Cruz");
        e1.setFirstName("Juan");
        e1.setSalary(10000);

        e2.setEmpID(1002);
        e2.setLastName("Ramos");
        e2.setFirstName("Fidel");
        e2.setSalary(12000);

        System.out.print("EMP ID    LASTNAME    FIRSTNAME       SALARY");
        System.out.print("e1.getEmpID()+ " " e1.getLastName()+ " " e1.getFirstName()+ " "    e1.getSalary()+ " " ");

    }
}
```

And this is the other class that I made for the "setters and getters." I have a private class too. This is the class that I'm having a hard time to access.

```
public class Employee {

    private int empID;
    private String lastName, firstName;
    private double salary;

    public void setEmpID(int emp){
        empID=emp;
    }

    public void setLastName(int ln){
        lastName=ln;
    }

    public void setFirstName(int fn){
        firstName=fn;
    }

    public void setSalary(int sal){
        salary=sal;
    }

    public int getEmpID(){
        return empID;
    }

    public String getLastName(){
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName(){
        return firstName;
    }

    public double getSalary(){
        return salary;
    }
}
```

When I'm compiling it, it has errors on my brackets and semicolons. I already fixed it but I still see the same errors. I'm also not sure if I'm doing the right thing. My outputs on "System.out.print" statement are not yet done because I haven't placed a variable "e2" in there. Can someone help me with my error? Also with how I can make the main class access the other class "Employee." I'm very sorry because I am still new to Java programming. Thanks.

Comment: And how do you "run" it ?

Comment: Just for start, this

Employee e1=new Employee;
Employee e2=new Employee;

should be

Employee e1=new Employee();
Employee e2=new Employee();

Comment: This `"e1.getEmpID()+ " " e1.getLastName()+ " " e1.getFirstName()+ " "    e1.getSalary()+ " " "` is not a valid String.

Comment: The method `setLastName(int)` is taking an `Integer` value and trying to assign that to a `String` variable. Please look into such thingies, there are plenty in the code you pasted :-) Every method should use compatible types. One cannot do `String str = 123`, since they not compatible with each other, one being `String` and another being `Integer`. You need to convert them or use `String str = "123"` for it to work or convert them in respective form.

Comment: Oohhhhhhhhh yeah wow sorry thanks @nIcEcOw

Comment: Elliott Frisch yes i noticed ill work on it. so do i have to remove the " "

Comment: @user3767918 I think you wanted `"" + e1.getEmpID()+ " " e1.getLastName() + " " + e1.getFirstName() + " " + e1.getSalary()`; I personally think it's a better idea to override `toString()` in `Employee`.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch  thanks now my next and hopefully last problem is how will i access the employee class coz it wont. they're on same folders already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `Employee` file and `EmployeeMain` file are in the same folder, you will not have to import it.

However, if they are in different folders, you will have to import them. This introduces the concept of packages.

After you correct your errors, I am sure you are recompiling them. Arent u?

`Employee e1=new Employee()`
You missed the parentheses there.

Comment: thanks now i get it but still have errors on my system.out.print ill try to work on it hmm

Comment: Ready to help. Post them here if you want.

Answer (score 2):

I am finding lot off issues in your program, please take a time to learn basics of Java. So, one of the issue is:

```
Employee e2=new Employee;
```

This is not the way you create new object in Java. You need to have `()`, like this:

```
Employee e2=new Employee();
```

Also you're missing import statements in your program (assuming you have forgotten to include this)

Comment: @Pradeed Simha thanks thanks now i have a new error on my system.out ill try to fix it

Answer (score 2):

ignoring other issues in your code, to answer your main question : 
try

> System.out.print(e1.getEmpID()+" "+e1.getLastName()+ "
>   "+e1.getFirstName()+" "+ e1.getSalary()+ " ");

Comment: thank you. what does it mean when i cant access the "Employee" which is a class